# angularjs: getting highest value from several variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using some calculations I have assigned some values for variables.

```
            console.log("Gain_weight is "+ Gain_weight);
            console.log("Gain_smoking is "+ Gain_smoking);
            console.log("Gain_exercising is "+ Gain_exercising);
            console.log("Gain_foodhabits is "+ Gain_foodhabits);
            console.log("Gain_parent_heartattack is "+ Gain_parent_heartattack);
            console.log("Gain_alcohol "+ Gain_alcohol);
            console.log("Gain_occupation "+ Gain_occupation);
            console.log("Gain_workinghrs "+ Gain_workinghrs);
```

Here I have values for Gain_weight, Gain_smoking etc.. How to select the variable with highest value assigned in AngularJS?

Comment: You can use the Max method:
Math.max(n1,n2,n3,...,nX)
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp

Comment: would changing the assignment of variables into an associative array be possible?

Comment: Question shows no attempt whatsoever to solve problem. This isn't a code writing service and you are expected to at least show attempts to solve problems yourself

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also want to know which value was the highest:

```
var gains = [Gain_weight, Gain_smoking, Gain_exercising, Gain_foodhabits, Gain_parent_heartattack, Gain_alcohol, Gain_occupation, Gain_workinghrs];
var gainLabels = ['Gain weight', 'Gain smoking', 'Gain exercising', 'Gain foodhabits', 'Gain parent heartattack', 'Gain alcohol', 'Gain occupation', 'Gain workinghrs'];
var maxGainValue = -Infinity;
var maxGainIndex = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < gains.length; i++) {
  if (maxGainValue < gains[i]) {
    maxGainValue = gains[i];
    maxGainIndex = i;
  }
}

console.log('The highest gain is ' + gainLabels[maxGainIndex] + ': ' + maxGainValue);
```

If you only care what is the highest value:

```
var maxGainValue = Math.max(Gain_weight, Gain_smoking, Gain_exercising, Gain_foodhabits, Gain_parent_heartattack, Gain_alcohol, Gain_occupation, Gain_workinghrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct data structure. For this case, one with a total-ordering like a [Binary Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) or a [Skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) seems appropriate. Using a [red black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), (e.g. [this implementation](https://github.com/vadimg/js_bintrees)) the solution becomes trivial:

```
var RBTree = require('bintrees').RBTree;
var tree = new RBTree(function(a, b) { return a.gain - b.gain; });

tree.insert({name: 'Gain weight', gain:1});
tree.insert({name: 'Gain smoking', gain:2});
// e.t.c...

tree.max();
// => {name: 'Gain smoking', gain:2}
```